# C# Newtonsoft.Json - Adicionar propriedade durante a serialização

Tags: c#, json, newtonsoft

Olá!

Estou tentando customizar a serialização de uma classe usando a biblioteca Newtonsoft.Json.
Minha intenção é adicionar uma propriedade no JSON **durante a serialização** do objeto.

Seguindo a [documentação oficial](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm), consegui implementar um `JsonConverter` customizado para adicionar a propriedade. No entanto, quando tenho objetos aninhados, não consigo aplicar o `JsonConverter` nos objetos filhos.

Criei um exemplo simplificado para demonstrar o que ocorre:

#### Objetivo

Adicionar a propriedade "TemFilhos" (`true` ou `false`) no JSON durante a serilização.

#### Alvo

A classe **Pessoa** será o alvo da serialização. Se tiver algum filho na coleção, a propriedade "TemFilhos" do JSON deve ser `true`, senão `false`.

```cs
public class Pessoa
{
    public Pessoa() { }

    public Pessoa(string nome, params Pessoa[] filhos)
    {
        Nome = nome;
        if (filhos?.Length > 0)
            Filhos = new List<Pessoa>(filhos);
    }

    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public List<Pessoa> Filhos { get; set; }
}
```

#### JsonConverter

Esse é o `JsonConverter` customizado que vai adicionar a propriedade "TemFilhos" durante a serialização.

```cs
public class PessoaJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(Pessoa);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var pessoa = (Pessoa)value;

        JObject o = JObject.FromObject(pessoa);

        // Adiciona a propriedade "TemFilhos" (true / false)
        o.AddFirst(new JProperty("TemFilhos", new JValue(pessoa?.Filhos?.Count > 0)));
        o.WriteTo(writer, this);
    }
}
```

#### Execução

O código abaixo faz a serialização da classe **Pessoa** usando o `JsonConverter` customizado.

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var ancestral =
            new Pessoa("Goku",
                new Pessoa("Gohan", new Pessoa("Pan")),
                new Pessoa("Goten")
            );

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ancestral, new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            Converters = new List<JsonConverter> { new PessoaJsonConverter() }
        });

        Console.WriteLine(json);
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

#### Resultado Esperado

O objetivo é criar a propriedade "TemFilho" para todas as instâncias da classe **Pessoa**.

```js
{
    "TemFilhos": true,
    "Nome": "Goku",
    "Filhos": [
        {
            "TemFilhos": true,
            "Nome": "Gohan",
            "Filhos": [
                {
                    "TemFilhos": false,
                    "Nome": "Pan",
                    "Filhos": null
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "TemFilhos": false,
            "Nome": "Goten",
            "Filhos": null
        }
    ]
}
```

#### Resultado Obtido

A propriedade "TemFilhos" foi criada apenas na primeira instância da hierarquia (Goku).

```js
{
    "TemFilhos": true,
    "Nome": "Goku",
    "Filhos": [
        {
            "Nome": "Gohan",
            "Filhos": [
                {
                    "Nome": "Pan",
                    "Filhos": null
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Nome": "Goten",
            "Filhos": null
        }
    ]
}
```

Se alguém conseguir me ajudar, ficarei muito agredecido!

#### Edição 1

Acho que não me expressei bem na postagem inicial. Sei que existem outras maneiras (muito mais simples) de adicionar essa propriedade ao JSON, bem como as soluções **alternativas** apresentadas nos comentários e respostas desta postagem até agora.

No entanto, o código em que estou trabalhando é muito mais complexo do que este exemplo que construí. Estou desenvolvendo um tipo de plugin para o meu programa, e eu não tenho controle sobre os tipos que serão serializados/deserializados. O primeiro passo, seria ter um mapa de `Chave => Tipo`, e fazer a `Chave` ser gerada em uma propriedade do JSON, para depois utilizá-la na Deserialização.

Já fiz testes usando a opção `TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects` do `JsonSerializerSettings`, onde ele gera uma propriedade chamada `$type` no JSON, com o nome completo do tipo da classe. É mais ou menos isso o que eu preciso, mas quero ter controle sobre o nome e o valor da propriedade que será gerada.

Em resumo, minha dúvida não se trata de como adicionar a propriedade "TemFilhos" no JSON, mas sim como dominar a implementação da classe `JsonConverter` ao ponto de conseguir adicionar a propriedade que preciso com ela.

Comment: A menos que a intenção seja outra, não seria mais prático menos suscetível a erros declarar um getter `TemFilhos` na sua classe? Algo do tipo `public bool TemFilhos { get { return this.Filhos.Count > 0; } }`

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda @user140828! Mas não era bem isso que procurava. Editei a postagem explicando melhor a situação.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solução

Consegui achar uma solução. O meu problema estava em converter a instância da classe em um `JObject` antes de prosseguir com a serialização. Quando eu fazia isso, o tipo da classe era perdido, e por isso as instâncias filhas não passavam pelo `JsonConverter`.

A solução foi transformar os dados em um dicionário, e serialização o dicionário.

```cs
public class PessoaJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(Pessoa);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var pessoa = (Pessoa)value;

        var dic = new Dictionary<string, object>()
        {
            {"TemFilhos",  pessoa?.Filhos?.Count > 0 },
            {nameof(pessoa.Nome ), pessoa.Nome },
            {nameof(pessoa.Filhos ), pessoa.Filhos}
        };
        serializer.Serialize(writer, dic);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá!

Eu faria desse jeito. Primeiro adicionaria um Id e um ParenteId a classe Pessoa.cs

```
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public int? ParenteId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Pessoa> Filhos { get; set; }
```

Em seguida criaria um função recursiva para adicionar os filhos, fazendo a buscar pelo Id == ParenteId, caso tenha filhos adiciona ao pessoaAtual.

```
    static IEnumerable<Pessoa> ConstruirRelacao(Pessoa pessoaAtual, Pessoa[] pessoas)
    {
        var filhos = pessoas.Where(c => c.ParenteId == pessoaAtual.Id).ToArray();

        foreach (var filho in filhos)
            filho.Filhos = ConstruirRelacao(filho, pessoas);

        pessoaAtual.Filhos = filhos;
        return filhos;
    }
```

Agora na classe Program crio uma lista passando os objetos para ela, referenciado o Id pai aos filhos(ParenteId). Em seguida chamo a função para criar a relação do Pai e filhos.

```
        IList<Pessoa> pessoas = new List<Pessoa>()
        {
            new Pessoa(){Id = 1, Nome = "Goku", ParenteId = null, Filhos = new List<Pessoa>() },
            new Pessoa(){Id = 2, Nome = "Gohan", ParenteId = 1, Filhos = new List<Pessoa>() },
            new Pessoa(){Id = 3, Nome = "Pan", ParenteId = 2, Filhos = new List<Pessoa>() },
            new Pessoa(){Id = 4, Nome = "Goten", ParenteId = 1, Filhos = new List<Pessoa>() },
        };

        var Pai = pessoas.Where(i => i.ParenteId == null).FirstOrDefault();

        Program.ConstruirRelacao(Pai, pessoas.ToArray());

        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Pai));

        Console.ReadKey();
```

Retorno:

```
{
   "Id":1,
   "Nome":"Goku",
   "ParenteId":null,
   "Filhos":[
      {
         "Id":2,
         "Nome":"Gohan",
         "ParenteId":1,
         "Filhos":[
            {
               "Id":3,
               "Nome":"Pan",
               "ParenteId":2,
               "Filhos":[
                  
               ]
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "Id":4,
         "Nome":"Goten",
         "ParenteId":1,
         "Filhos":[
            
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Não sei se era isso que você queria realmente, mas espero ter ajudado em algo.

Att,

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Lucas! Não era bem isso que eu precisava. Editei a postagem para explicar melhor a situação. Quero consegui fazer usando `JsonConverter`.